# Converter reverse_iterator para iterator?

Tags: c++, string

Estou escrevendo um interpretador de XML em C++, quando encontrar uma má formação no XML gostaria de mostrar a linha e coluna do erro. Estou trabalhando com iterators da string e criei uma função para formatar o erro conforme a seguir:

```
string msgLocalizadaXML(string::const_iterator aItIni, string::const_iterator aItFim, string::const_iterator aItMsg)
{
   string linha = "Linha...: " + to_string(count(aItIni, aItMsg, '\n') + 1) + '\n';
   constexpr auto numCaracteres = 25;

   auto itQuebra = find(reverse_iterator<string::const_iterator> { aItMsg },
                        reverse_iterator<string::const_iterator> { aItIni },
                        '\n');                                 
   // Linha do erro
   string coluna = "Coluna..: " + to_string(distance(itQuebra, aItMsg) + 1) + '\n';

   string contexto { max(aItIni, aItMsg - numCaracteres), min(aItFim, aItMsg + numCaracteres) };
   replace(contexto.begin(), contexto.end(), '\n', ' ');
   contexto = "Contexto: " + contexto + "\n"
              "          " + string(static_cast<size_t>(distance(max(aItIni, aItMsg - numCaracteres), aItMsg)), '~') + '^';

   return linha + coluna + contexto;
}
```

O erro retornado GCC 4.8.1:

```
XMLDocumento.cpp:420:86: error: no matching function for call to 'distance(std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> > >&, std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator&)'
```

O erro é porque os iterators para a função distance tem que ser do mesmo tipo, mas como busco de traz pra frente ele me retorna um reverse, como converto para um iterator?

tentei construir um std::string::iterator com itQuebra mas ele não deixou.

Comment: `itQuebra.base()`

Comment: deu certo! nem precisou decrementar a base para usar na chamada a distance `string coluna = "Coluna..: " + to_string(distance(itQuebra.base(), aItMsg) + 1) + '\n';`. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @pepper_chico Considere transformar isso em uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme especificado nos comentários da pergunta, a resolução ocorreu usando `itQuebra.base()`.

Assim, o código foi alterado de:

```
string coluna = "Coluna..: " + to_string(distance(itQuebra, aItMsg) + 1) + '\n';
```

Para:

```
string coluna = "Coluna..: " + to_string(distance(itQuebra.base(), aItMsg) + 1) + '\n';
```